# Proof of sets operations equivalency 2

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying set theory at University and I just discovered this site. I hope it's not too anoying if I keep asking questions about this subject.

This is the exercice:
Let X, Y and Z be sets. Prove the following statement:
X∆(Y∆Z) = (X∆Y)∆Z

This is what I've done:
By definition A∆B=(A-B)∪(B-A) Then I can apply the following reasoning:
x∈X∆(Y∆Z) ⇔ (x∈X^x∉Y∆Z)∨(x∈Y∆Z^x∉X) ⇔ (x∈X^¬((x∈Y^x∉Z)∨(x∈Z^x∉Y)))∨(((x∈Y^x∉Z)∨(x∈Z^x∉Y))^x∉X) At this point I thought that maybe I was taking the wrong aproach, but I kept developping in hopes of getting something that would finnaly transform into something equivalent to (X∆Y)∆Z

(x∈X^¬((x∈Y^x∉Z)∨(x∈Z^x∉Y)))  ∨  (((x∈Y^x∉Z)∨(x∈Z^x∉Y))^x∉X)

⇔ (x∈X^((x∉Y∨x∈Z)^(x∉Z∨x∈Y)))  ∨  {([{x∈Y^x∉Z}∨x∈Z]^[{x∈Y^x∉Z}∨xY])^x∉X}

Here I've written many things, but I don't know in which direction I should head. What I've done is apply the distributive law and have a long list of ands and ors. Was I heading in the right direction? The real porpouse is to prove X∆(Y∆Z) = (X∆Y)∆Z so if you know a way to prove it that doesn't use anything of what I've done tell me.

Answer (score 0):

First prove that an element $x$ belongs to $X\Delta(Y\Delta Z)$ if and only if it belongs to an odd number of the sets $X,Y,Z$, i.e., exactly one or else all three of the statements $x\in X,x\in Y,x\in Z$ hold.

Then prove the same thing for membership in $(X\Delta Y)\Delta Z$. This doesn't require a whole new proof; since $(X\Delta Y)\Delta Z=Z\Delta(X\Delta Y)$ (I assume you already know that $\Delta$ is commutative), it's the same thing with the letters permuted.

Suppose $x\in X\Delta(Y\Delta Z)$. There are two cases: either $x\notin X$ or $x\in X$. **Case 1.** Suppose $x\notin X$. Then $x\in Y\Delta Z$, which means that either $x$ is in $Y$ but not $Z$, or else $x$ is in $Z$ but not $Y$. Hence, either $x$ is in $Y$ alone, or else $x$ is in $Z$ alone. **Case 2.** Suppose $x\in X$. Then $x\notin(Y\Delta Z)$ . . .

Alternatively, if you know about characteristic functions and modular arithmetic, forming the symmetric difference $X\Delta Y$ of two sets just means adding their characteristic functions modulo $2$, so all you need is that addition modulo $2$ is associative. (This "alternative" is really the same thing with added jargon.)

Comment: I get the idea of what I have to do, but proving that equivalency seems hard to me. I know that what I have to do is prove this: x∈XΔ(YΔZ) ⇔ (x∈X^x∉Y^x∉Z)∨(x∉X^x∈Y^x∉Z)∨(x∉X^x∉Y^x∈Z)∨(x∈X^x∈Y^xx∈Z) How do I prove that?

Comment: I forgot to say that I don't know anything about characteristic functions or modular arithmetic.

Comment: If you don't know about characteristic functions etc., just ignore the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: All those logical formulas make my head spin; I'd use some **words** too. I will add some more explanation to my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply to your comments, had a power outage at my house so I couldn't get on the internet.